# transactional.id.expiration.ms doesn't expire producer ids when set manually

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want to enforce a certain behaviour that's why I've set `transactional.id.expiration.ms: 1000` via strimzi and verified that it will be picked up by the broker too.
My expectation is that the producer ids expire after 1 second too, but this doesn't happen as all the producers continue producing without issues.

Comment: Hm, it took way longer than one second for the producer ids to expire, something like 10-20 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

There is another property responsible for that

```
 transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms
```

Reference https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#transaction-remove-expired-transaction-cleanup-interval-ms